# The inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It is known that $\mathbb{Z}$ is equipotent to $\mathbb{Q}$. However, when we construct the quotient field $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ using fraction, there is an injective map $x\mapsto x/1$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then by identification, we have $\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Q}$. But the set of all $x/1$ is a proper subset of the quotient field $\mathbb{Q}$, then $\mathbb{Z}$ is "smaller" than $\mathbb{Q}$. So can I claim that whether $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ is equipotent depends on the map from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Equipotence is defined by the existence of _any_ bijection between the two; the fact that some maps are not bijections doesn't change the existence of ones that are.

Comment: $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ defined by $n\mapsto 2n$ is a proper injection. $\mathbb Z$ is still equipotent to itself.

Comment: There is a reason to not use “smaller” when talking about infinite sets this way. It eventually becomes intuitive, but I think a better way to think about it early on is to think in terms “more or less complex.” So $\mathbb Z$ is the same complexity as $\mathbb Q.$ The choice of the word “equipotent” is meant to give some distance from the intuition of “size.”

Comment: The comments by Thomas Andrews and Steven Stadnicki point up the vagaries of trying to extend notions from finite sets to infinite sets. There are clearly integers that are not even. Naievely, one would be tempted to say that the set of integers must be "bigger than" the set of even integers. This reasoning neglects the fact that there is a one-to-one-correspondence between the elements of the two sets. But, the existence of such a correspondence between finite sets is exactly how we determine if they have the same number of elements.

Comment: As Thomas says, it is useful to have a term that tries to avoid naieve, intuitive impressions. In addition to equipotent, I have seen the terms equivalent and equinumerous used in this context (and, I believe, equipollent, but I'd have to chase that one down).